# Combining repeating items in a list

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of items containing unique and repeating IDs, I want to sum the prices and display the number of the repeating IDs

```
class Model{
  int id,price,count;
  Model(this.id,this.price,this.count);
}

List<Model> list1 = [
  Model(1,5000,10),
  Model(2,1000,20),
  Model(1,5000,5),
  Model(2,5000,10),
];

List<Model> list2 = [];
```

I need the second list to be like this

```
 list2 = [
  Model(1,10000,15),
  Model(2,6000,30),
];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
void main() {
  int sum = 0;

  List<Model> list1 = [
    Model(1, 5000, 10),
    Model(2, 1000, 20),
    Model(1, 5000, 5),
    Model(2, 5000, 10),
  ];

  List<Model> list2 = modelsWithoutRepeatingIdsButSumOfPricesAndAmount(
      list1); // [Model(1,10000,15), Model(2,6000,30),]
}

List<Model> modelsWithoutRepeatingIdsButSumOfPricesAndAmount(
    List<Model> modelList) {
  Map<int, Model> map = {};

  for (int index = 0; index < modelList.length; index += 1) {
    Model current = modelList[index];
    map[current.id] ??= Model(current.id, 0, 0);
    map[current.id]!.price += current.price;
    map[current.id]!.count += current.count;
  }

  return map.values.toList();
}

class Model {
  int id, price, count;
  Model(this.id, this.price, this.count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce method to get the sum of a list

```
var total = [1, 2, 3].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
```

If you don't want to use reduce method you can also use .fold() there are couple more you can get them by importing dart collections package.